# Alternatives to Inkscape for EPS tagging for psfrag

Tags: graphics, eps, psfrag

So it seems the latest version of Inkscape is not very `psfrag`-friendly: If you insert text tags into your EPS then upon saving (even if you deselect "Convert text to paths") it still encodes the tags as things like `<01>Tj`, which can be worked around by manually replacing each by something like `(mytag)Tj` in the EPS source, but cumbersome if one has lots of EPS files to tag.

Is there another way people are doing their tagging now? perhaps another vector graphics program, or another way to insert text into EPS all together?

Comment: This issue came up with Inkscape v0.47 when they started using cairo for the `pdf` and `ps`/`eps` export and is reported as a bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/375323). Note comment #90 from two days ago (2012-03-26): “Now that cairo 1.12 has now been released, psfrag compatible postscript output is available with a stable version of cairo.”